# Search not working no suggestions in WELT PEARL THEME "Ajax Auto Complete"

Tags: ajax, search, elasticsearch, autocomplete, elastic

I have just fixed the problem searches in the search field offered no product results

It was nothing to do with Pearl Theme, we are quite sure it is because of some legacy attributes that did not work with elastic search.
The site was a Magento 1 site and back then I used attributes to assist with the menus pre Mega Menu

Our checking process was to disable Ajax (didnt work), reinstall Ajax(didnt work) change to default theme (didnt work), reverted to out of the box search by turning off Ajax that sort of worked, change attributes to non searchable not all of them just the ones that did not need to be searchable (worked)